# Should I use 'are' or 'were' when talking about event in the past

Tags: grammar, tenses

In this sentence, I'm talking about something that occurred in the past, but it's something cultural so it's a thing that happens every time, like if I am to attend an Indian event in the future I'm going to get free samosa as well. Given that context I wonder if the tenses I used in this sentence is correct:

> There were free samosa at every Indian event that I attended

should I use *were* or *are* in this context?

Comment: 1. In English the plural of samosa is 'samosas', at least here in the UK: "Samosas are fried, triangle-shaped pastries stuffed with a spicy vegetable filling" 2. You attended (past tense) so there were (past tense) free samosas.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey okai thank u so much :)

Comment: "There have been free samosas at every Indian event that I've attended" (so far - so I assume this will continue to be the case).